# How to set a Type Literal on a widened type parameter (or prevent type widening)?

Tags: typescript, types, type-inference

I want to create a function that produces a "Factory" of strong typed objects. These objects have an attribute called "tag" which is a `string`, but I want to make this string a `string literal`.

This is needed to implement a somewhat "AbstractFactory" pattern, in other words, a group of functions that creates a object that creates the desired object, like so:

```js
//Over Simplified Version

type Factory = {
  a: (name: string) => { tag: name };
  b: (name: string) => { tag: name };
};

type Names = {
  a: "A";
  b: "B";
};

type Result = {
  a: { tag: "A" };
  b: { tag: "B" };
};

function(factory): (names) => result
```

The catch is that this "tag" objects have extra properties, and I need the this string literal to properly use them.

I have made various experiments with this concept, what I got is this:

```js
// Implementation

type Tag<T extends string> = { tag: T };

type Factory<
  TKey extends string,
  TName extends string,
  TTag extends Tag<TName>
> = {
  [key in TKey]: (name: TName) => TTag;
};

type Names<TFactory extends Factory<any, any, any>, TName extends string> = {
  [key in keyof TFactory]: TName;
};

type Result<
  TFactory extends Factory<any, any, any>,
  TNames extends Names<TFactory, any>
> = {
  /**
   * I am almost sure that the problem lies here, maybe because I am
   * not passing the required generic, I just can't figure it out.
   */
  [key in keyof TNames]: ReturnType<TFactory[key]>;
};

function implementation<
  TKey extends string,
  TName extends string,
  TTag extends Tag<TName>,
  TFactory extends Factory<TKey, TName, TTag>,
  TNames extends Names<TFactory, TName>,
  TResult extends Result<TFactory, TNames>
>(factory: TFactory): (names: TNames) => TResult {
  return (names) => {
    const keys = Object.keys(factory) as Extract<keyof TFactory, string>[];
    return keys.reduce((result, key) => {
      const name: TName = names[key];
      (result as Record<string, TTag>)[key] = factory[key](name);
      return result;
    }, {}) as TResult;
  };
}

const factory = implementation({
  a: (name: string) => ({ tag: name, index: 2 }),
  b: (name: string) => ({ tag: name, name: "Bob" }),
});

const result = factory({ a: "A", b: "B" } as const/* names */);

result.a.index; // the index type got inferred properly
result.b.name; // the name type got inferred properly

result.a.tag; // the tag type got widened to string, I want to be string literal "A"
result.b.tag; // the tag type got widened to string, I want to be string literal "B"
```

I think I am kind of overusing generics. I am quite sure there is a simpler approach to this.

TL;DR: I want to prevent a string literal to be widened to `string`, so my `tag` properties become the literals that I provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a more ideal solution than this, since I usually prefer to avoid type intersects (`&`) in TypeScript. Not that they're necessarily bad practice but they tend to produce less readable type hints in the tooltips on editors than when using other approaches.

```
interface Tag<T extends string> {
  tag: T;
}

interface Factory {
  (name: string): Tag<string>;
}

interface FactoryMapper {
  [key: string]: Factory;
}

type Names<TMapper extends FactoryMapper> = {
  [TKey in keyof TMapper]: string;
}

type Result<TMapper extends FactoryMapper, TNames extends Names<TMapper>> = {
  [TKey in keyof TMapper]: ReturnType<TMapper[TKey]> & Tag<TNames[TKey]>;
}

function implementation<TMapper extends FactoryMapper> (mapper: TMapper) {
  return <TNames extends Names<TMapper>> (names: TNames) => (
    Object.keys(mapper).reduce<Partial<Result<TMapper, TNames>>>(
      (result, key) => Object.assign(
        result,
        { [key]: mapper[key](names[key]) }
      ),
      {}
    ) as Result<TMapper, TNames>
  );
}

const factory = implementation({
  a: name => ({ tag: name, index: 2 }),
  b: name => ({ tag: name, name: "Bob" }),
});

const result = factory({ a: "A", b: "B" } as const);

result.a.index; // the index type got inferred as number
result.b.name; // the name type got inferred as string

result.a.tag; // the tag type got inferred as "A"
result.b.tag; // the tag type got inferred as "B"
```

The key part of this solution is the definition of the `Result` type:

```
type Result<TMapper extends FactoryMapper, TNames extends Names<TMapper>> = {
  [TKey in keyof TMapper]: ReturnType<TMapper[TKey]> & Tag<TNames[TKey]>;
}
```

which narrows the definition of the resulting member using the intersect. The rest of the code above should also help exemplify how to better write your type parameters for generics.

Comment: I cant't thank you enough. I was almost there but you simplified everything. Thank you very much.